Confusion with the meaning of virtual com port
As far as I read, plugging a USB mouse into a PC is not creating a virtual port; but plugging a serial to USB converter does.
This is very confusing for me since from PC operating system's point of view it both sees a USB connection. I tried to depict is as follows:

What makes one a virtual COM port and the other not?
My confusion is more fundamental. USB is also a serial protocol. Why does it have to be emulated by a virtual port inside the PC? Basically what's the difference between virtual com port and a physical com port and why we need virtual one. The converter already translates it to USB signals. But why still virtual com port necessary?

"The converter already translates it to USB signals" - indeed, and that's the problem. Software that expects a "dumb" RS232/UART signal doesn't understand USB. So you need to convert it back. Or write software that deals directly with USB CDC. But if you're going to do that, might as well do it just once, call it a driver, and let all other software that already dealt with RS232 work as if they were directly connected.

this is a virtual leaf ... https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_today-ss-slide-desktop,f_auto,q_auto:best/MSNBC/Components/Slideshows/_production/ss-140203-camouflage-bugs/ss-140203-camouflage-bugs-tease.jpg

the USB to serial adapter is a hardware serial port, not virtual ... a virtual serial port is created by software, such as com0com

@jsotola But only real physical 8250 compatible UART serial ports are real COM ports. i.e. USB serial ports are not COM ports, which is why any manufacturer making USB UART serial chipsets need to make drivers how to provide an emulation layer for their chip to look like a COM port so any program opening and using COM ports via Win32 API can work with it. In Linux all UARTs show up as TTYs so same there, the USB UARTs need to have drivers to have same API as the other UARTs. It's not about the adapter being virtual.

@Justme that makes sense ... the 8350 can be accessed with a simple peek and poke

@user4444 because the hardware device expects to talk to serial port hardware and the associated software expects the device to be connected to a serial port ... the use of the USB is just a convenience ... the serial adapter could also be connected to the computer in some other way, on a LAN for example

All USB devices have one or more classes. The simplest USB devices have one Class.
Things like mice and keyboards are of the USB HID class (Human interface device). These generally have low bandwidth communication but are more responsive (soft real time guarantees on timing)
USB storage devices are of the USB MSC (Mass storage) class. These allow for high speed transfers.
Serial ports are of the USB CDC (Communication Device) class, which are about midway between the two in terms of low latency vs throughput.
USB also allows for Composite devices which have more than one Class. These could be two or more interfaces of the same Class or different classes.
When you plug in a USB device, the host reads the USB descriptors to know what the device class is and what endpoints are available. USB VID (vendor ID) and PID (product ID) are used to determine what driver can be used for the device.

My confusion is more fundamental. USB is also a serial protocol. Why does it have to be emulated by a virtual port inside the PC? Basically whats the difference between virtual com port and a physical com port and why we need virtual one. The converter already translates it to USB signals. But why still virtual com port necessary? I hope I could explain my confusion.

Serial does not mean a specific interface. It just indicates that data is transmitted roughly one bit at a time (sort of). This data is framed and packed in different ways, with different additional features and transmission speeds and so on. PCI Express is also a serial protocol, and many others exist. The actual underlying protocols for Rs232 and USB are extremely different. The USB virtual com ports use the USB serial transport to send data, but the usb device then converts the data from the USB protocol to the older, much simpler, much slower RS232 protocol.

And on the PC side, the virtual COM port is needed so that software or users which want to communicate with an RS232 device can do so without caring about the USB interface. They pretend it's RS232 and communicate simply with it. The 'conversion' to USB on the computer and back to rs232 on the adapter are done transparently. If you don't want a VCP, with the FTDI devices for example, you can use the D2xx driver instead and manage all of that yourself. It can be exponentially more complicated.

@user4444 Not all serial interfaces are the same. The "COM port" (also "RS-232 port" or "TTL serial port" or "UART port") are like the Ford Model T of serial communication. It's old and crude, and dates back to ancient time of electronics. They're still used in embedded systems because of simplicity, so when we say "serial ports" it's a shorthand of the old-school ones. Meanwhile, USB is also a form of serial interface, but uses sophisticated signaling, hardware and software tech. There's no surprise that translation hardware is needed to connect both kinds of serial ports together.

Programs could communicate directly with USB devices, and that's fine.  And many do.
But that doesn't help programs that don't know (or don't go to the trouble of figuring out) USB devices.
Consider the use-case where a legacy application ran on a legacy PC for many years.  The PC fails, it's upgraded, and lo and behold, the new PC does not have a parallel port at all, or enough serial ports* -- whatever the application needed.  And maybe there was an expansion card to provide extra ports, but it's in a now-unsupported format (ISA, PCI).  So, you're screwed, right?
*Even modern motherboards generally still have one or two serial, I think, though it might be hidden on a header, not taken out to the rear panel.
Well, what can we do about it?  Say the application still runs on the latest operating system, maybe having to use compatibility settings, but all the old interfaces still work, it's not crashing, it just needs device access.  A common method is to open COM/LPT ports as a character-mode file; this is typical from Unix to MS-DOS to Windows.  If only we had a driver that presented as a character-mode device, we could map our new-fangled USB or PCIe* devices to it.
Thus, the virtual COM port driver was born.
*To be fair, PCIe isn't less compatible, you can get COM port cards in that format just as well.  Though I don't know offhand if they present as COM ports natively, or also load a virtual device.  But it seems, USB does not offer the same capability.
This might not be an accurate retelling of development, I'm completely uninvolved in the design of these things: devices, drivers, OS development -- but more to say, a possible sequence of events, a need and a substitute.  Often, such devices don't work nearly as well as one would hope*, but for the average case when an application is well-behaved and going through the OS to do device/file access, it's very likely to work.
*A very old counterexample might be, bit-banging the control/status signals on the COM port, via direct CPU-port access.  Port access is a big no-no for user-mode programs on protected-mode operating systems (basically anything since MS-DOS, and anything Unix unless user has root), and would cause a protection error and crash.  Such access can be intercepted through emulators like DOSBox, but the compatibility depends on how well the attached (USB/etc.) device can actually perform the equivalent operations; and likely the bits won't be banged with the correct timing anyway (gated by how often the OS schedules the running program, and services the device -- IO operations are generally collected into a buffer and handled in batches, since changing context to handle very granular (single bit/byte) operations is very wasteful).
The success of such a low-level substitute depends on many things; with suitable device, it might be that the emulator can insert enough delays, and structure IO requests, to more closely (but still not identically) reproduce original timing.  Without a suitable device (say a USB UART that only offers the basic port configuration settings required by the OS, no arbitrary control of status signals), maybe no degree of (software) effort can get there.

The USB protocol has a number of device classes that represent standard things that could be inserted into a computer and allows them to be communicated with using a generic driver rather than forcing each device to distribute its own driver.  One of these is the human interface device class that includes things like mice and keyboards.  Another is the USB communications device class (CDC) which includes things like USB Com ports.
To answer your question, if you mouse identifies as a USB HID device to your PC, it will load the USB HID driver. If it chose to identify as a USB CDC device, it could appear as a USB com port (although I don't think it has to).  In the case of a USB to RS-232 adapter, it will almost certainly choose to be a CDC device to enable using the standard driver in Windows.

My confusion is more fundamental. USB is also a serial protocol. Why does it have to be emulated by a virtual port inside the PC? Basically whats the difference between virtual com port and a physical com port and why we need virtual one. The converter already translates it to USB signals. But why still virtual com port necessary? I hope I could explain my confusion.

@user4444 Ease of programmability for one. USB is a rather complex protocol, takes more development time on both ends to set up. Simple COM serial communications with a UART on one end and Windows's COM API functions on the other could almost be called trivial in comparison.

@user4444 Serial port usually refers to the RS-232 standard, which is more than 60 years old.  Aside from the name, there is little in common between RS-232 and USB.  The ability to emulate an older serial port is useful since a lot of software is able to communicate over a serial port but not a lot of computers still have 1960s/70s era physical ports anymore (although you can certainly still get them on modern PCs if you want).   They do however have USB, so USB emulation of a com ports can be very handy in that case.

@user1850479 Technically, the "serial port" or more spcifially "COM" port on PCs has referred to an RS-232 serial communications port implemented with 8250 UART or modern version of it. RS-232 standard does not even mandate the protocol so it does not require UART protocol.

On connect, a USB device communicates its device class, and vendor id and product id, and also a string that gives textual information on what it is.
The operating system uses all that information to decide which driver should handle that particular USB device. That driver is what creates the “virtual COM port” for the USB-RS232 converter within the computer.

My confusion is more fundamental. USB is also a serial protocol. Why does it have to be emulated by a virtual port inside the PC? Basically whats the difference between virtual com port and a physical com port and why we need virtual one. The converter already translates it to USB signals. But why still virtual com port necessary? I hope I could explain my confusion.

Because "serial protocol" says nothing. There's a plethora of serial protocols. USB is one. RS232 is another. The naïve user software does not know anything about USB. It's programmed for a software abstraction of an RS232 UART. That “virtual COM port” hides everything that is USB from the user software.
